# How to Index Match Array with between two numbers

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

I have a table that looks like this.

| ID | Low Number | High Number | Risk |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAA | 0 | 33 | None |
| AAA | 34 | 75 | Moderate |
| BBB | 0 | 54 | Low |
| BBB | 55 | 100 | High |
| CCC | 0 | 25 | N/A |
| CCC | 26 | 50 | Mild |
| CCC | 51 | 100 | Severe |

I want to do a index/match on the ID and the Numbers and return the "risk" but only if the number I am looking up on is between the "Low Number" and "High Number"

So lets say I have an ID of AAA and a Value of 35. I would want to return Moderate frome the risk Risk

Here is what I have tried.

```
=INDEX($D$1:$D$32,MATCH(1,(G1=$A$1:$A$32)*(H1>=$B$1:$B$32)*(H1<=$C$1:$C$32)),0)
```

I used it as an and array formula. CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER. Still no luck.

I had the ID in G1 and the Value in H1.

Any guidance is apprecaiated as always.

Comment: Your formula should work, but you have not used the last parameter of `MATCH()` function. `=INDEX($D$1:$D$32,MATCH(1,(G1=$A$1:$A$32)*(H1>=$B$1:$B$32)*(H1<=$C$1:$C$32),0))` And since you have not mentioned the `0` it has taken as `1` which is default value for this argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using <kbd>XLOOKUP( )</kbd> this can also be accomplished. However using <kbd>INDEX( )</kbd> & <kbd>MATCH( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>J1</kbd>

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$8,MATCH(1,(H1>=$B$2:$B$8)*(H1<=$C$2:$C$8)*(G1=$A$2:$A$8),0))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>I1</kbd>

```
=XLOOKUP(1,(H1>=$B$2:$B$8)*(H1<=$C$2:$C$8)*(G1=$A$2:$A$8),$D$2:$D$8)
```

---

> ***Y**our formula would work, but you have missed out the* **last parameter** *of*
> *the* <kbd>MATCH( )</kbd> *function, if not entered then the default*
> *value of the argument is taken as* <kbd>1</kbd> *which does an*
> **approximate match**, *while you need an* **exact match** *hence had to*
> *specifically enter* <kbd>0</kbd>, *since we are looking at the operation*
> *which does a* <kbd>Boolean Logic</kbd> *to check whether the value falls within a*
> *range of values or not and based on* <kbd>ID</kbd>

---

**Here is MS Documentation:**

[image]

**[MATCH( )](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/match-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a)** Function doucmentations

---

So that said the correction to your formula will be, also you can use <kbd>XLOOKUP( )</kbd> if using either **Excel 2021** or **MS365**

```
=INDEX($D$1:$D$32,MATCH(1,(G1=$A$1:$A$32)*(H1>=$B$1:$B$32)*(H1<=$C$1:$C$32),0))
```

---

**One last caveat:** Based on Excel Version one needs to hit the <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> while exiting the edit mode.

---